# SSIS Data Conversion - Update Multiple Rows

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

First SSIS experience so I'm willing to accept I'm doing things completely wrong here:

Using SSIS:

- I'm importing from an Excel sheet
- exporting to a client's SQL (SQL Server) database
- The data has >250 columns
- The Client's database rows are all various nvarchar lengths like 3,5,8, etc
- I can assume that the excel data will fit into the database properly, so if I truncate I won't lose any data

What I think I have to do here is truncate the data using a "Data Conversion" transform. The problem I have is it's going to take me hours to do this in the "Data Conversion" editor window because I'm dealing with so many columns, when it would only take me a few minutes in a text editor.

Is there any way to bulk update the Data Conversion settings? Am I doing this the wrong way?

Comment: You can set your package to not fail on truncation. This link http://salvoz.com/blog/2011/12/27/ssis-handling-truncation-and-data-errors/ shows how to redirect to a file but instead you want to "Ignore Failure". Unfortunately Excel is a really unreliable data source and you will no doubt other problems with it

Comment: This helps part of the problem. The other half is that now all of my "Data Conversion" outputs are named "Copy of <row>", so I have to do in and manually set all those in the output step. Any thoughts on that one?

Comment: I don't think you need a data conversion at all. The ignore error is changed in the source. I haven't done this before, I've just read about it so I can't guide you directly

Comment: I think you're right. I just removed the data conversion and told it not to truncate on failure and now it's going through. Thanks

Comment: Great. If you could take the time to document what you did and post it as an answer, it'll help the next person looking for this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up with was:
- change the package to not fail on truncation. 
- Once I did this I could get rid of the transform.
- in the database I created a staging table with the excel column names to import to so that I didn't have to manually match everything up in SSIS